# create new user for internet use only

Tags: permissions, login, internet

I want to create a new user who has the ability to access internet and put any of their downloaded files to his/her pen drive. That's it. He/she should not be able to install any new software. Should not be able to navigate to any other folder other than their home folder. Should have the access to Firefox only to access Internet.

Is it possible to do this in Ubuntu? If so, please guide me in how to do it?

I want to create this sort of a user account, so when a friend/relative of mine wants to use my laptop to access Internet for browsing, and downloading any files they need, I want to give them access to this account.

Thank you.

Comment: On the login screen, you can choose "Guest user". Does that meet your needs? (try logging out and choosing "Guest user" instead of your normal user account)

Comment: *"Once in a while a friend, family member, or colleague may want to borrow your computer. The Ubuntu Guest Session feature provides a convenient way, with a high level of security, to lend your computer to someone else. A guest session can be launched either from the login screen or from within a regular session. If you are currently logged in, click the icon at the far right of the menu bar and select Guest Session. This will lock the screen for your own session and start the guest session."* ...

Comment: ... *"A guest cannot view the home folders of other users, and by default any saved data or changed settings will be removed/reset at logout. It means that each session starts with a fresh environment, unaffected by what previous guests did."* https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html

Comment: @NickWeinberg You should probably expand that a bit and post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu actually has a built-in "guest user" account that might meet your needs. You can enter a guest session from the user switcher or by logging out and then choosing "Guest user" instead of your normal username.

To quote the Ubuntu help page about it:

> Once in a while a friend, family member, or colleague may want to borrow your computer. The Ubuntu Guest Session feature provides a convenient way, with a high level of security, to lend your computer to someone else. A guest session can be launched either from the login screen or from within a regular session. If you are currently logged in, click the icon at the far right of the menu bar and select Guest Session. This will lock the screen for your own session and start the guest session.
>
> A guest cannot view the home folders of other users, and by default any saved data or changed settings will be removed/reset at logout. It means that each session starts with a fresh environment, unaffected by what previous guests did.

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html

You might want to give it a try (since it doesn't require any extra software or setup) and see if it's what you're looking for.

Please let me know if this is helpful, or if you have any further questions!

Comment: Thank you everyone for your support. I guess I'll stick with the inbuilt Guest account. I found that after reading all of the information you guys have provided, it's the best thing to do.